# How to reference an object and change its values

Tags: java

So i'm creating a tile based game and currently working on hovering on tiles i have the hovering sorted so that when you hover over an image it changes colour but i am stuck with how to remove the colour when the next tile is hovered upon.

```
Tile previous;
public void CheckHover() {
    for (Tile t  : map.getTiles()) {
        if (t.IsMouseOver(screen.getMousePosition().x, screen.getMousePosition().y)) {
            t.setMouseOver(true);
            if (previous == null) {
                previous = t;
            } else {
                previous.setMouseOver(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code above does not quite work i believe it may be down to how i am referencing the object but if i am doing a for each loop how can i get object that is currently hovered and setMouseOver to false?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you store `previous` somewhere in the class that contains `CheckHover()` (btw, check the naming conventions, it should better be `checkHover()`).

Thus you need to update `previous` whenever the mouse is over a different tile.

Here's some pseudocode for your loop:

```
boolean hovering = false;
for( Tile t : tiles ) {
  if( t.mouseOver(...) ) {
    //assuming t is never null, t.equals(...) will also work if previous is null
    if ( !t.equals( previous ) ) {
      if( previous != null ) {
        previous.setMouseOver(false);
      }
      previous = t;
    }
    //else nothing to do, still hovering over the same tile

    hovering = true;
    break; //no need to look further
  }
}

//reset when not hovering over any tile anymore
if( !hovering && previous != null ) {
  previous.setMouseOver(false);
  previous = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Learn [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) - You will definitely need to know this; particularly the `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` methods.  If you don't need all the methods of the `MouseListener` interface, you can extend the `MouseAdapter` abstract class and overriding those two methods I mentioned.
2. Learn [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) - I think you can take advantage of layered panes to achieve what you want by giving the appearance that the tile has changed colors when the above mouse events are triggered.

**UPDATE**:

I found this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629473/component-layering-java-swing-layers-showing-on-hover) that might be exactly what you need to do.  Go there and try the suggested code and try to adapt it to what you are trying to do.  I believe it will work great for your particular case.